# Non Commutative Multiplication of each element for any number of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have two lists

```
list1={a1,b1}
list2={c2,d2,e2}
```

We need the output in the form

```
{a1**c2,a1**d2,b1**c2,b1**d2}
```

Please suggest some procedure to do this.

Comment: Have a look at `Outer` and `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

Comment: try also `Tuples[NonCommutativeMultiply[list1, list2]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following example:

```
Flatten[Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, {a1, b1}, {c2, d2}, {e3, f3}],3]
```

which returns

```
{a1 ** c2 ** e3, a1 ** c2 ** f3, a1 ** d2 ** e3, a1 ** d2 ** f3, 
 b1 ** c2 ** e3, b1 ** c2 ** f3, b1 ** d2 ** e3, b1 ** d2 ** f3}
```